# How can I create a nav bar that is responsive relative to your location on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

I created this nav bar recently, it's the first nav bar I've made and I'm quite happy with it, that being said it didn't fully meet my vision:

[image: First Nav]

What I am trying to create is a nav bar that will respond relative to where you are on the page. For example if I'm at the top of the *about* section it would look like this:

[image: Mock up 1.]

As you continue to scroll through the various sections, they would scroll along side the nav bar, once reaching the top of the next section sitting at the top underneath the previous.

I've looked at Spyscroll but I haven't seen anything on the docs, nor any examples anywhere else of it having being responsive the the manor I described. Rather I see it being either on the section or off the section.

I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction as I'm sure something like this is possible, unfortunately I'm quite new to web dev and you don't know what you don't know!

On a side note I'm also curious as to if this is a bad idea from a UI/UX standpoint as I haven't been able to find any examples of this.

**Edit for clarity**

I am not asking for help to fix broken code. I'm asking if what I'm looking to achieve is feasible and what I need to look into to create it.

If you're interested in seeing the code for the nav bar I created previously it is available here:
[Simple Navigation Bar](https://github.com/Kal-Toh/Simple-side-Nav-with-hover-effect)

Comment: Please create a demo of the code that you tried so others can help you with it.

Comment: Why is this tagged with JS, HTML, and CSS, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: @m4no As stated, I've not been able to confirm the feasibility of creating this, let alone start coding it. I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction on how it would be possible.

Comment: @NicoHaase It is tagged with HTML and CSS as that's what my previous nav bar was written it. It's tagged with JS as I think JS may be needed to achieve what I'm looking to achieve.

To reiterate, I'm not looking for code snippets or to fix anything that's broken. I'm asking how it would be possible to achieve a result outlined in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this. With IO you can observe sections and react whenever they intersect with either each other or the viewport (that's what you want)

First, you have to specify the options for IO:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '-50px 0px -55%' // whatever suits your usecase, see documentation for this!
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

then you define what elements you want to observe, something like:

```
let entries = document.querySelectorAll('section');
entries.forEach(entry => {observer.observe(entry);})
```

Last step is to define what should happen if an element is intersecting:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
     //specify what should happen if an element is coming into view, like defined in the options. 
    }
  });
}, config);
```